# How can I extend a bundle more than once?

Tags: exception, inheritance, symfony, bundle

In my Symfony2 app I'm having a very basic bundle named `AnimalsBundle()` with a very basic entity.

I can successfully extend this bundle by creating a new bundle `MammalsBundle()` via [Bundle Inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html). However, it is not possible to register one further bundle `InsectsBundle()` that also extends the `AnimalsBundle()`. Whenever I'm trying to do this, Symfony throws a

> [LogicException]
>    Bundle "AnimalsTextBundle" is directly extended by two bundles "MammalsBundle" and "InsectsBundle".

So out of the box it's obviously not allowed. First of all, I'm not really sure why this is not allowed and - most important - how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's been more than year now, but I just came across your question and the answer maybe useful to someone anyway..

Symfony doesn't allow a bundle to be extended directly by more than one bundle, simply because if two bundles are overriding the same files, it wouldn't be possible to determine what bundle should be used. However you can achieve what you want by doing the following :

`AnimalsBundle` <|---- `MammalsBundle` <|----- `InsectsBundle`

This way InsectsBundle indirectly has AnimalBundle as a parent and can override files from it.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably not the most elegant solution but as long as multiple BundleInheritance does not work (and yes, your explanation makes sense), this seems to be the only way to go.

Comment: When you think about it, it's actually pretty logical. I wanted to extend a bundle more than once, in an inherit kinda way. But it's really for overriding the parent bundle only.

Answer (score 1):

I know, that this has been a log time since the question has been asked, but for those in need of an answer I'll suggest the following:

1) Try to avoid bundle inheritance except the cases you are 100% positive that you need to.

2) Given the example in question, the better setup will look smth like this: you have a `CreatureBundle`, which consists mostly of abstract classes and interfaces. Make each descendant bundle depend on `CreatureBundle` and implement each `Creature` specific code with those abstract classes and interfaces in `CreatureBundle`.

Based on personal experience I can tell that managing dependencies is much easier task than managing inheritance issues in case something goes wrong. If you'll ever need to alter the ancestor bundle's logic, you'll save yourself lot time by not having to dig through inherited code and alter the same logic in every descendant bundle.

Edit: Although my suggestions might lead to tighter coupling and basically contradicts latest Symfony's 'best practices' guide (which states that '*single bundle per app*' is a best practice), in the end you'll realize that this approach eventually makes code maintenance easier.

Answer (score -1):

I can't think of a use case where you could possibly need to do this. Bundles are meant to be almost like standalone applications. You have the dependency injection container at your disposal if you need resources from another bundle.

Perhaps you should re-think your project structure.

Comment: I wanted to inherit the bundles because the child bundles use most of the functionality but should be able to overwrite behaviour some of the parent bundles functionality (like the controller or replacing a class in it by simply putting a file with the same name into the child bundle or extending the entity). I don't know what approach is the right one.

Comment: You can still use standard PHP object inheritance for models, controllers, etc. The only reason I would use bundle inheritance would be to override Twig templates - but even then, there are ways around it.

Comment: Interesting, I was precisely trying to override Twig templates to have a differente error page for each bundle but I got this error. What other ways are there around ?